# Distribution of degree in graphs: when is the friendship paradox the paradox it wants to be?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, network-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\deg{deg}\DeclareMathOperator\ndeg{ndeg}\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}$The [friendship paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_paradox) goes *most people have fewer friends than their friends have on average*. The original paper [Feld - Why your friends have more friends than you do](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2781907) has a simple counter example: [image] (Figure 5, p. 1474).

My question is how exceptional is this example?

Even in some random graph models where some answer is tractable, the analysis of the [distribution of a neighbour's degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_distribution#Excess_degree_distribution) deals with expectation. That is, in some models it is explicitly shown that *the average difference between the mean number of friends of friends and the number of friends is positive*, which is much less likely to get press attention I think.

Given any graph $G=(V,E)$ and $v\in V$, let $N(v) = \{w\in V:\{v,w\} \in E\}$ and $\deg(v) = \abs{N(v)}$. This is the number of friends of $v$. Now consider $\ndeg(v)= \sum_{w \in N(v)}\deg(w)$, the total friends of friends of $v$ and the distribution of
$$
f(v) = \frac{\ndeg(v)}{\deg(v)} - \deg(v).
$$
For a friendship paradox,
$$
g = \abs{\{v:f(v)>0\}}-\abs{\{v:f(v)<0\}}>0.
$$
For the graph pictured above,
$$
\{f(v)\}_{v\in \{A,B,C,D,E,F\}}=\left\{ 1,1,-\frac13-\frac13,-\frac13,-\frac13 \right\}.
$$
Clearly $g = -2$, and no paradox. But, the mean of $f$ is $1/9>0$.

The mean of $f$ is [shown to be positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_distribution#Excess_degree_distribution) in the popular configuration model. And this is usually said to be evidence/proof of the friendship paradox. (Tangential question: is $g>0$ in this model?)

Now the question(s):

1. Is the mean of $f$ positive for any graph?
2. What are some equivalent conditions stated in terms of graph properties to $g >0$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can answer question 1, at least. The mean of $f$ is always positive (unless every connected component of the graph $G$ is regular, in which case the mean of $f$ is zero). To see this, we rewrite the sum of the values of $f$ as

$$\sum_{v \in V} f(v) = \sum_{v \in V} \sum_{w\text{ s.t. }\{v,w\} \in E} \left(\frac{\deg(w)}{\deg(v)} - 1\right) = \sum_{\{v,w\} \in E} \left(\frac{\deg(w)}{\deg(v)} + \frac{\deg(v)}{\deg(w)} - 2\right),$$

and each summand is positive by AM-GM. More explicitly, we have

$$\sum_{v \in V} f(v) = \sum_{\{v,w\} \in E} \frac{(\deg(v)-\deg(w))^2}{\deg(v)\deg(w)} \ge 0.$$